# How to Mock java.util.Scanner for a FileInput

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I'm having a problem to mock an input from a STDIN way file running in a CommandLineRunner. I've tried it in several ways, but whenever I run the test the application asks me to insert the file on the command line.

My Command line class:

````
@Slf4j
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    private AutorizadorService service;

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        log.info("provide file path:");
        service.init(scan.nextLine());
        scan.close();

    }
} ```

MyCommandLineTest class 1 try:

``` @SpringBootTest
public class CommandLineRunnerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private CommandLineRunner clr;

    @Test
    public void shouldRunCommandLineIntegrationTest1() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("D:/j.json");
        System.setIn(new FileInputStream(file));
        this.clr.run();
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldRunCommandLineIntegrationTest2() throws Exception {
        Scanner mockScanner = mock(Scanner.class);
        when(mockScanner.nextLine()).thenReturn("D:/j.json");
        mockScanner.nextLine();
        verify(mockScanner).nextLine();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRunCommandLineIntegrationTest3() throws Exception {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("D:/j.json".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
    }

}
````

Running any of this tests i see this in command line, and only pass if i enter manually the input

```
2021-08-21 15:56:36.327  INFO 14772 --- [           main] b.c.a.r.CommandLineAppStartupRunner      : provide file path:
```

Comment: Your first test runs the code you're testing *before* you redirect `System.in` to your file. Your second test doesn't run your code, and your third test just redirects input. You don't provide a mock `AutorizadorService`. Please explain what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: Hi Man, i edit my post, and update the description. 
I'm looking for a way that when running CommandLineRunner I don't need to manually enter the file path in unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint at the start of your `run` method, you'll see that running a `@SpringBootTest` actually runs the application, i.e. it calls the  `run` method on any runners it finds.

You should test that class with a non-springboot test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CommandLineAppStartupRunner.class})
public class CommandLineRunnerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private CommandLineRunner clr;

    @Test
    public void shouldRunCommandLineIntegrationTest1() throws Exception {
        System.setIn(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.json"));
        this.clr.run();
    }
}
```

Your class slightly simplified:

```
@Component
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (!scan.nextLine().equals("{ \"foo\":  \"bar\"}")) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

You'll need to add any other configuration needed to the `@ContextConfiguration` on the test class.

Comment: Thank's its very helpful!